# how to publish obtaining id $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, authentication

I briefly explain what my problem is. I'm building in php, a website that allows you to post job advertisements. My tables are three, owner_company, companies, job_advertising

owner_company : -id -name -surname -email -password

companies : -id -company_user -company_password -owner_id

job_advertising : -id -company_id -owner_id -description -salary

once a user has registered as a business owner, his data will be stored in the owner_company table and he will then have to log in to enter his administration area. In the login of the owner_company I have implemented a variable $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id']; that you take the id of this last one. Login code that allows you to enter the administrative area

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
$messaggio = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include 'connessione.php';

//REAL_ESCAPE_STRING ANTI STRINGA BUCA DB

$email = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$password = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$query = $connessione->query("SELECT id, password FROM titolare_azienda WHERE email='$email'");

if ($query->num_rows > 0) {

$data = $query->fetch_array();

if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {

//IMPLEMENTAZIONE SICUREZZA PER ACCESSO AI DATI SOLO SE LA SESSIONE DELLA LOGIN PAGE E' UGUALE ALLA PAGINA DOPO DEL LOGIN

$_SESSION['sessione_azienda'] = true;
$_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];

$messaggio = "Accesso effettuato correttamente! <a href='Azienda/index.php'>Accedi alla tua Dashboard</a>";

}else

$messaggio = "Please check your inputs!";

}}

?>
```

Nothing prevents a company owner from having more companies and therefore in its administrative area has been implemented a page dedicated to the registration of the company where the data entered will go into the company table, in filling out the form and entering data of it, I entered the value $ owner_id = $ _SESSION ['id']; so that at the end of the compilation I know that the company created will correspond to a specific id of the owner

now I have my problem after the owner has registered his company, he in his administrative area has a dedicated page to view all the companies created by him, thanks to an inner join between owner_company and companies that benefits from the $ id = $ _SESSION [ 'id']; set during login

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../connessione.php';

$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$query_string = "SELECT * 
FROM aziende
INNER JOIN titolare_azienda 
ON aziende.titolare_azienda_id = titolare_azienda.id 
WHERE aziende.titolare_azienda_id ='$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);
?>
```

so until now I have the data of the owner of the company and I have created a company, where the latter I know is associated with the owner's ID. At this point I decided that among the data of the compilation concerning the company to insert two fields company_user and company_password, this because once the user is in the page of his companies, suppose for example that he owns two companies A and B and he will have the username and password for A and the same for B, these two fields will serve him to be able to publish a job ad so that by logging in I can bring the company id and through an innerjoin I can get the values ​​of the company that has efefttuato the login, and quadno it will publish an ad I can have the id of the owner id id company and id of the ad, now I leave here written my inner join my goal is to view after the login with company credentials, only the company in question, how do I do it?

innerjoin after login:

```
<?php

session_start();

include '../connessione.php';


$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$query_string = "SELECT * 
FROM aziende
INNER JOIN titolare_azienda
ON aziende.titolare_azienda_id = titolare_azienda.id
WHERE titolare_azienda.id = '$id' ";

$query = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);

?>
```

Comment: you need to pass the company id to a controller then do a simple select query

Comment: The nicest thing I can do right now ... is be a little bit of a jerk, and say that for the sake of your sanity and the project outcome - you NEED to move to a framework with an ORM.  User->hasMany('comapnies') ... An orm will write your relational queries for you in a secure reliable way.

Comment: User->with('Companies.Jobs')... You'll love using an ORM.

Comment: Take a look at laravel.com

Comment: hahahahah yes tarek, i know with laravel it's more easy, but i need to build it, with no framework ... HELP ME !